# Downloadable Sample Link not working

Tags: magento-1.9, downloadable, sample

In the backend, the sample of the `downloadable product` is an **URL** (*not a File*).
In the frontend, when I click the sample link, it just opens another window and redirects to the product page. Users can't get to the sample.

I'm running `Magento 1.9`. Just realized the problem today. Any idea?

Downloadable Information screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What the file type you have tried to use as sample?

Comment: MP3. It's a full URL like https://www.example.com/example.mp3.

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot of the 'Downloadable Information' section of the product, please?

Comment: Updated the question. Please check. Really appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no ability to set the external URL of the samples without a code customization.

Comment: What? What is the URL field meant to be?

Comment: The URL to the current site that Magento has been installed. The file uploading way isn't suitable you, right?

Comment: That is my magento site's URL, not an external website. We have many products, so I batch uploaded the files to the server. Then I set it up this way. It was working. Not sure when it stopped. In the frontend, the sample link is like: `https://www.example.com/downloadable/download/linkSample/link_id/123/` but it just redirects to the product page....

Comment: I have tried to add sample to the mp3 file that has been uploaded by myself on the site like you. So the sample opens up in the new window properly. I have tried do it from the directory in the root of the site and from the media  one. Lets see the permission for your sample directory and the samples. Looks like the problem is there. For this establish a ssh conection to your site and go to parent directory of the samples one and execute `ls -ls`, for example. After that, go to the samples directory and do the same.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice. It inspires me to find the real problem. So I forced https throughout the entire site a while ago. Looks like the sample link mechanism doesn't like the redirection as well as https. I modified the .htaccess to exclude the sample folder. Now it's working! Thanks.